# бесконечная 2D анимация заднего фона (C# unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d

хочу сделать анимацию заднего фона в простой 2D игре, чтобы при нажатии на клавиши движения, вслед за персонажем начинал в нужную сторону двигаться задний фон.
Пробовал сделать так для начала

```
public GameObject gg; // за кем следить
    Renderer r;
    public float offset = 0.01f;
    Vector2 offsetTexture = Vector2.zero;
    float lastpos;
   
    void Start()
    {
        lastpos = gg.transform.position.x;
        r = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        offsetTexture = r.material.mainTextureOffset;
    }
       void Update()
    {
        if(lastpos!= gg.transform.position.x)
        {
            offsetTexture.x += (lastpos - gg.transform.position.x) * offset  ;
            r.material.mainTextureOffset = offsetTexture;
            lastpos = gg.transform.position.x;
        }
    }
```

но это не сработало.

Comment: это называется Parallax effect. погуглите

Comment: Спасибо. Все получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос кажется решён, но если вдруг нужна плавная перемещение то вот:

```
public class Follow2D : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform target;
    public Vector3 pose;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    public float speed = 0.1f;


    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        pose.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(pose.x, target.position.x, ref velocity.x, speed);
        pose.y = Mathf.SmoothDamp(pose.y, target.position.y, ref velocity.y, speed);
        transform.position = pose;


    }
}
```